# kendo grid How to get a row by field value

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to get a row(s) from my kendo grid, using a string as parameter to filter rows.
the grid model is:

```
{
    id: "id_tipo_pagamento",
    fields: {
        id_tipo_pagamento: { type: "number", editable: false },
        desc_tipo_pagamento: { type: "string"}
}
```

i tried this, but isn't working:

```
 var grid = $("#kendoGrid").data("kendoGrid");
 var row = grid.tbody.find("tr[desc_tipo_pagamento=test]");
```

Comment: What about using filter? do you really want to use HTML DOM?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of using DOM, I would suggest using `jQuery.grep` on the `DataSource.data` array (if you want all) or in `DataSource.view` if you want from the current visible ones.

Example:

```
// Retrieve all data from the DataSource
var data = grid.dataSource.data();
// Find those records that have desc_tipo_pagamento set to "test"
// and return them in `res` array
var res = $.grep(data, function (d) {
    return d.desc_tipo_pagamento == "test";
});
```

`res` will contain a reference to the records in DataSource that matched the condition.

Comment: OnaBai,  What about if once you have the record, you then want to also select the corresponding row in the grid?  The doco only shows how to select a row by index of the <tr>.  How do you do it by primary key?

Comment: How can I, for example, add a class to the rows that come inside the `res` variable?

Comment: What about a template?

Comment: I am using a column template with a checkbox in it. When I click the checkbox, I want to select the row in which the checkbox is. In my javascript, after clicking the checkbox, I manage to get the row model id, but now I want to do something like `row.addClass("k-state-selected");` but I don't know how to make the `row` variable the actual grid row (where the clicked checkbox is)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922110/selecting-a-row-from-a-kendo-grid-programmatically) is my question, could you please help?

Comment: Perfect answer @oneBai