# Move dataItem (row) to first place in Kendo grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I want to be able to move specific row to first place on first page in a paginated Kendo grid.  I have found the dataItem via jQuery but I am not sure how to append it as the first element in the grid.  I couldn´t find anything similar to this in the documentation but only on how to [removeRow](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#methods-removeRow).  Can anyone perhaps help me in moving the dataItem to firstplace?

Here´s my script where I´ve found the dataItem:

```
function onFetchItem(gridName) {
    var ids = gridName.split("_");
    var item = $("#ItemSearch_" + ids[1]).val();
    var grid = $("#" + gridName).data("kendoGrid");
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var dataItem = $.grep(data, function (d) {
        return d.Item == item.toUpperCase();
    });
    //TODO: move dataItem as first record in grid
}
```

I found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276994/kendo-grid-how-to-get-a-row-by-field-value) that I could use greb as I suggest above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first remove the item and then insert it at first index:

```
grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
grid.dataSource.insert(0, dataItem);
```